# i'm having an error with my discord bot each time i run it i get this error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\all in one bot\cafe-musain-bot\bot.py", line 79, in <module>
    client.run('OTU1NjAyMjY1NzEwOTQ0Mjc2.YjkD9g.n0Qqhng0EA63JOcxwzajjm--wi0')
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 304, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000022765565550>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

here is the code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

token = 'Token'
intents=discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")
the rest...

client.run(token)
```

i tried restting the token multiple times and checked that the token is a string nothing happens same error, tried making a new discord application guessing that the problem is in the one im already using got the same error asked in the discord.py guild no one knew how to fix it.

Comment: Please Give A Minimal Reproducible Example Like Code Snippets So That We Can Help You On The Issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also What It Seems Is That There is A Authorization Error. Please Check if You Have Given Your Bot All The Privilege's It Needs For It To Run And Proper Authentication Is Initiated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the improved code. First make sure to create a `config.py` file in your main directory containg the following:

```
TOKEN="Your Token"
```

And here is the `main.py` code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from config import TOKEN

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")
'''
The rest Goes Code Here
'''
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: thnx worked just fine

Comment: btw i want to upload the bot into github so i can run it on heroku do i commit the files with the _pycache_ file or not?

Answer (score 2):

Without code, it's hard to give an accurate answer, but this sounds like your bot token is incorrect.

The line of the error that suggests your token is incorrect/improper:

```py
 raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
```

How to ensure the bot starts correctly:

```py
token = ''
bot.run(token) # client.run(token)
```

You can find your token [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications/). You need to ensure that the token is correct - otherwise, authentication will not succeed.

Comment: worked once then retried and crached **added code in the post**

Comment: Have you enabled all intents in the developer portal (https://prnt.sc/b3of9hS05LYv)?